# What information can be seen when I'm using SRTP via XMPP?

Tags: encryption, tls, privacy, voip, xmpp

Just as the title goes, basically what data/information can be tracked when using SRTP via XMPP?

As client I'm using Jitsi. If things works in some aspects similar to HTTPS, I guess that maybe it can be seen to what server I'm connecting for my XMPP account, anything else? Can they tell if I'm doing a text/audio/video chat? sending files? Can they tell who am I conversing with?

I'm quite naive in these things, and hope I'm not overlooking something basic.